# Is there any offline application for Kanban or Trello?

Tags: software-recommendation, productivity

Are there any offline applications that support or work with Trello?

Also, is there any offline tool that performs a similar function (kanban) ?

Comment: Your question has already been answered [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20240/is-there-a-way-to-use-trello-offline). The comments below the answer are also relevant to your question.

Comment: @karel Thats pretty old. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20240/is-there-a-way-to-use-trello-offline#comment36237_20242

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 applications I could find:

- https://greggigon.github.io/my-personal-kanban/
- http://virtualkanban.net/
- http://dmitryivanov.net/

or you can [use your evernote as kanban](http://dottech.org/173057/how-to-organize-evernote-notes-like-trello-tip/) with:
http://www.kanbanote.com/

Also feel free to [vote on trello for offline support](https://trello.com/c/ig5IZyJn/291-offline-support).

Edit: Trello [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trello&hl=en&gl=US) now comes with an offline feature:

> Trello works offline! Add information to your boards and cards at any
> time and it will be saved for when you need it. We got your back.

Comment: Thanks! I like the first one, greggigon/my-personal-kanban . However, this can be improved.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the apps mentioned in the answers aren't really offline apps.
However, you can give [Brisqi](https://brisqi.com) a try, it's an offline-first Kanban app with a focus on privacy. It runs completely offline, you don't really need the internet to use it unless you want to sync your data to other devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Kanbanik](http://kanbanik.github.io/kanbanik/) for your Kanban requirements. It can be installed locally and accessed via a suitable web browser.

Documentation and source code is available via the project's [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kanbanik/kanbanik).

Answer (score 0):

Try Projscope Tasks - Offline Kanban tool (http://Projscope.com). It is a clean and simple task management tool build with Kanban methodology in mind! Dragging task between areas will speed up task management and improve overall clarity

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of **F|P App**, of which the first major chunk I've released is a speedy **[Trello integration](https://trello.com/integrations/#/focus%7CProject)**.

This can be used as a reduced functionality PC Trello client in practice ... with some extras, including **read-only offline support**.

In more details it currently supports a board history for on/offline use in the form of fast to access, searchable local [data snapshots](https://f-p.app/snapshots.html).

[image: You can choose to view historic board states. Fear not there's also a bright theme!]

I'd otherwise put it as **a todo ticker/note taker** (incl. annotated images as attachments combined with a live markdown preview).

**It's still in beta**, but in my experience it works out well on at least Ubuntu as a lightweight short-range PM aide for the web (or electron) based heavier artillery.

You should be able to simply install it from Ubuntu Software under the `focus-project` name, or via the console:

```
snap install focus-project
```

At the moment it works off either a developer token (albeit that may or may not be a stretch for some - if it's prohibitive, let me know!) or a password-restricted, but more proper authorization for beta testers on Linux (ask! :) ).

Hope this helps!

Janos (2021)